# Group outer collection based on a property value of nested (inner) collection

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a collection A which internally has a collection B as one of its property. I want to group all the items of the outer collection A based on a value of a property of the inner collection.

```
class A
{
    string A;
    List<B> NestedColl;
}

class B
{
    string key;
    string name;
    int id;
}
```

Now I have

```
List<A> localCollection = new List<A>();
```

I want to group all the collection items based on the value of Id in the nested collection.

Comment: What you have tried? Show some attempted code first.

Comment: It sounds more like you want a simple OrderBy.   I.E. localCollection.OrderBy(itm => itm.NextedColl.id)

Comment: Rahul, whatever I tried would not build so right now I have written a for loop that is doing the job for me. I can share that code if you'd like to see that

Comment: Actually I need more than just an order by, since I have to process the items in a batch ( for a group), and if I just Orderby then I still have loop through and form groups. I was trying to not having to write a forloop for this.

Comment: @JasonBoyd supplied the correct answer and should be marked accordingly. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure what you want here.

If you had this

```
class A
{
    string A;
    B NestedB;
}

class B
{
    string key;
    string name;
    int id;
}
```

You could do this

```
localCollection.GroupBy(a=>a.NestedB.id);
```

But you have a nested collection so each B could have a different id and which would you group by?

You could go with the first like this

```
localCollection.GroupBy(a=>a.NestedColl.First().id);
```

Or you could go with the first biggest like this

```
localCollection.GroupBy(a=>a.NestedColl.Max(b=>b.id));
```

There are other options too but without knowing what you want I can't get more specific.

Answer (score 5):

Conceptually, this is a weird thing to try and wrap one's head around but this will do what you want:

```
localCollection
.SelectMany(a => a.NestedColl.Select(b => new { A = a, Id = b.id}))
.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Thankyou!!! I've been hacking around to solve this problem for hours! This answer should be marked the correct one...